# How can I setValidate on an element in the form from a directive?

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that links to a textbox on the form, and I would like for this directive to set the 'required' error.

Here's a fiddle that shows what I'm trying to do

http://jsfiddle.net/scottieslg/7qLsj3rr/3/

Html:

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='TestCtrl'>
    <ng-form name='testForm'>
        <input type='text' name='myInput' />
        <div ng-messages="testForm.myInput.$error">
            <div ng-message="required">Required</div>
        </div>
        <test-directive ng-model='testModel'></test-directive>
    </ng-form>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMessages']);

app.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.testModel = {}
});

app.directive('testDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        template: '<div><button ng-click="setError()">Set Error</button></div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {            
            scope.setError = function() {
                // How can I set .setValidate('require', true) on myInput from here??
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: why do you need `ng-model` on the `testDirective`?

Comment: It is unclear from your question what you want to do, please do update you question

Comment: You can't pretend that `required` validator should fail when the field has value. I think that you may be interested in creating your [custom validation logic](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `test-directive` to be able to control the `ngModelController` instance on a separate named input in a form, then using the `ng-model` directive again isn't the right thing to do, as that would create a new `ngModelController` instance on `test-directive`.

What the `test-directive` actually needs to know is the *name* of the input which has the controller:

```
<test-directive name='myInput'></test-directive>
```

Then it can access the form controller, using

```
require: '^form',
```

and use the `name` attribute value to find the `ngModelController` instance on the form:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, formController) {            
  scope.setError = function() {
    var ngModelCtrl = formController[attrs.name];
    ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('required', false);
  }
}
```

You can see this at http://jsfiddle.net/7qLsj3rr/6/ .

Note: if you're using `required` as the key, then as soon as you type in the input again again, angular's own `required` validation will kick in an remove the error.